# Trying to concatenate JavaScript objects created from within a map function but seeing Promise and Promise { undefined }

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, async-await, promise

I have a JS object with multiple arrays inside it. Each array has a "message" key and i have created a few lines of code that are able to filter out the specific arrays who's message value contain the word "INFO"

My goal is to create a new object i am calling finalLogDataObject which will contain only the filtered message keys

Let me give you an example of what I am trying to achieve

```
[{"id":3,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"id":2,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"id":1,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
```

And the original object is

```
[
            {
                "eventId": "12345",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551603,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1685441542538
            },
            {
                "eventId": "12345",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:42.539Z\txxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":3,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1684441542539
            },
            {
                "eventId": "12324",
                "ingestionTime": 1687491551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n",
                "timestamp": 1687941542540
            },
            {
                "eventId": "76543",
                "ingestionTime": 1689441551605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\tDuration: 1.26 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1687491542540
            },
            {
                "eventId": "65754",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441951605,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441593428
            },
            {
                "eventId": "76856",
                "ingestionTime": 1687941551605,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:43.429Z\txxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":2,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441543729
            },
            {
                "eventId": "57645",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxx\n",
                "timestamp":81687441543430
            },
            {
                "eventId": "567465",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441851605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxx\tDuration: 1.62 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1887441543430
            },
            {
                "eventId": "56476",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544359
            },
            {
                "eventId": "56885",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551405,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:44.360Z\txxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":1,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544360
            },
            {
                "eventId": "45343",
                "ingestionTime": 1644441551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxx\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544362
            },
            {
                "eventId": "34653",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441558605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxx\tDuration: 1.65 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441644362
            }
        ]
```

So far I have been able to filter out the correct fields containing the `INFO` key word and format them from within the map function however I have not been able to concatenate the arrays into a new object correctly. I have promises in the object returned from the map function and am also seeing multiple undefined values as well.

when I console log the variable object **finalLogDataObject** returned from my map function I am seeing this

```
[
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { { id: 3, key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' } },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { { id: 2, key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' } },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { { id: 1, key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' } },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined }
]
```

when i console log **formattedInfoLogMessages** from within the map function i am getting 3 arrays that look exactly how i need them.

```
console.log('formattedInfoLogMessages: ' + formattedInfoLogMessages)

// formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":3,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
// formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":2,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
// formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":1,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

How do i concat them into one object returned from map?

Here is my JavaScript file

```js
async function handler() {
    try {
        const initialLogDataObject = [
            {
                "eventId": "12345",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551603,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1685441542538
            },
            {
                "eventId": "12345",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:42.539Z\txxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":3,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1684441542539
            },
            {
                "eventId": "12324",
                "ingestionTime": 1687491551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n",
                "timestamp": 1687941542540
            },
            {
                "eventId": "76543",
                "ingestionTime": 1689441551605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\tDuration: 1.26 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1687491542540
            },
            {
                "eventId": "65754",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441951605,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441593428
            },
            {
                "eventId": "76856",
                "ingestionTime": 1687941551605,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:43.429Z\txxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":2,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441543729
            },
            {
                "eventId": "57645",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxx\n",
                "timestamp":81687441543430
            },
            {
                "eventId": "567465",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441851605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxx\tDuration: 1.62 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1887441543430
            },
            {
                "eventId": "56476",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544359
            },
            {
                "eventId": "56885",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551405,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:44.360Z\txxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":1,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544360
            },
            {
                "eventId": "45343",
                "ingestionTime": 1644441551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxx\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544362
            },
            {
                "eventId": "34653",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441558605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxx\tDuration: 1.65 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441644362
            }
        ]


        let finalLogDataObject = Object.entries(initialLogDataObject).map(async function ([key, item]) {

            let logStreamEventMessage = item.message

            if (logStreamEventMessage.includes("INFO") === true) {

                const formattedLogMessage = (String(logStreamEventMessage)).replace("\n", "")
                const filterByInfoKeyword = formattedLogMessage.split(/[  INFO  ]+/);
                const getInfoLogMessages = filterByInfoKeyword[1];
                const formattedInfoLogMessages = getInfoLogMessages.replace(/\s/g, "");
                const parsedInfoLogMessages = JSON.parse(formattedInfoLogMessages);
                
                console.log('formattedInfoLogMessages: ' + formattedInfoLogMessages)
                // formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":3,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
                // formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":2,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
                // formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":1,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
                return parsedInfoLogMessages

            }
        })

        // here is where I need the object to be [{"id":3,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"id":2,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"id":1,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]

        console.log(finalLogDataObject)
        // however when i console log i get
        // [
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { { id: 3, key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' } },
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { { id: 2, key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' } },
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { { id: 1, key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' } },
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { undefined }
        // ]

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

handler()
```

Any help on where I am messing this up would be great. Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces an array of `Promise` objects, because an `async` function *always* returns a `Promise`:

```
map(async function() { /*...*/ })
```

*If* you were performing asynchronous operations that needed to be awaited (but you're not, see further below) then you can `await` those promises with `Promise.all`.  So for future readers who are performing such operations within a `.map()` call and want to get the results of those operations, it might look like this:

```js
async function handler() {
    try {
        const initialLogDataObject = [
            {
                "eventId": "12345",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551603,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1685441542538
            },
            {
                "eventId": "12345",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:42.539Z\txxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":3,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1684441542539
            },
            {
                "eventId": "12324",
                "ingestionTime": 1687491551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n",
                "timestamp": 1687941542540
            },
            {
                "eventId": "76543",
                "ingestionTime": 1689441551605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\tDuration: 1.26 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1687491542540
            },
            {
                "eventId": "65754",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441951605,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441593428
            },
            {
                "eventId": "76856",
                "ingestionTime": 1687941551605,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:43.429Z\txxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":2,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441543729
            },
            {
                "eventId": "57645",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxx\n",
                "timestamp":81687441543430
            },
            {
                "eventId": "567465",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441851605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxx\tDuration: 1.62 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1887441543430
            },
            {
                "eventId": "56476",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544359
            },
            {
                "eventId": "56885",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551405,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:44.360Z\txxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":1,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544360
            },
            {
                "eventId": "45343",
                "ingestionTime": 1644441551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxx\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544362
            },
            {
                "eventId": "34653",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441558605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxx\tDuration: 1.65 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441644362
            }
        ]


        let finalLogDataObject = Object.entries(initialLogDataObject).map(async function ([key, item]) {

            let logStreamEventMessage = item.message

            if (logStreamEventMessage.includes("INFO") === true) {

                const formattedLogMessage = (String(logStreamEventMessage)).replace("\n", "")
                const filterByInfoKeyword = formattedLogMessage.split(/[  INFO  ]+/);
                const getInfoLogMessages = filterByInfoKeyword[1];
                const formattedInfoLogMessages = getInfoLogMessages.replace(/\s/g, "");
                const parsedInfoLogMessages = JSON.parse(formattedInfoLogMessages);
                
                console.log('formattedInfoLogMessages: ' + formattedInfoLogMessages)
                return parsedInfoLogMessages

            }
        })

        const result = await Promise.all(finalLogDataObject);

        console.log(result)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

handler()
```

**However**, in your specific case since the functions aren't performing any asynchronous operations, **just remove the `async` keywords entirely** so you're not unnecessarily using `Promise` objects in the first place:

```js
function handler() {
    try {
        const initialLogDataObject = [
            {
                "eventId": "12345",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551603,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1685441542538
            },
            {
                "eventId": "12345",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:42.539Z\txxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":3,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1684441542539
            },
            {
                "eventId": "12324",
                "ingestionTime": 1687491551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n",
                "timestamp": 1687941542540
            },
            {
                "eventId": "76543",
                "ingestionTime": 1689441551605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\tDuration: 1.26 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1687491542540
            },
            {
                "eventId": "65754",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441951605,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441593428
            },
            {
                "eventId": "76856",
                "ingestionTime": 1687941551605,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:43.429Z\txxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":2,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441543729
            },
            {
                "eventId": "57645",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxx\n",
                "timestamp":81687441543430
            },
            {
                "eventId": "567465",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441851605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxx\tDuration: 1.62 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1887441543430
            },
            {
                "eventId": "56476",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544359
            },
            {
                "eventId": "56885",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551405,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:44.360Z\txxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":1,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544360
            },
            {
                "eventId": "45343",
                "ingestionTime": 1644441551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxx\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544362
            },
            {
                "eventId": "34653",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441558605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxx\tDuration: 1.65 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441644362
            }
        ]


        let finalLogDataObject = Object.entries(initialLogDataObject).map(function ([key, item]) {

            let logStreamEventMessage = item.message

            if (logStreamEventMessage.includes("INFO") === true) {

                const formattedLogMessage = (String(logStreamEventMessage)).replace("\n", "")
                const filterByInfoKeyword = formattedLogMessage.split(/[  INFO  ]+/);
                const getInfoLogMessages = filterByInfoKeyword[1];
                const formattedInfoLogMessages = getInfoLogMessages.replace(/\s/g, "");
                const parsedInfoLogMessages = JSON.parse(formattedInfoLogMessages);
                
                console.log('formattedInfoLogMessages: ' + formattedInfoLogMessages)
                return parsedInfoLogMessages

            }
        })

        console.log(finalLogDataObject)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

handler()
```

---

Additionally, you'll still need to remove the `undefined` entries from the array to produce the result you're looking for.  You can use `.filter()` for that, returning only "truthy" objects:

```js
function handler() {
    try {
        const initialLogDataObject = [
            {
                "eventId": "12345",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551603,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1685441542538
            },
            {
                "eventId": "12345",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:42.539Z\txxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":3,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1684441542539
            },
            {
                "eventId": "12324",
                "ingestionTime": 1687491551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n",
                "timestamp": 1687941542540
            },
            {
                "eventId": "76543",
                "ingestionTime": 1689441551605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\tDuration: 1.26 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1687491542540
            },
            {
                "eventId": "65754",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441951605,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441593428
            },
            {
                "eventId": "76856",
                "ingestionTime": 1687941551605,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:43.429Z\txxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":2,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441543729
            },
            {
                "eventId": "57645",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxx\n",
                "timestamp":81687441543430
            },
            {
                "eventId": "567465",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441851605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxx\tDuration: 1.62 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1887441543430
            },
            {
                "eventId": "56476",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544359
            },
            {
                "eventId": "56885",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551405,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:44.360Z\txxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":1,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544360
            },
            {
                "eventId": "45343",
                "ingestionTime": 1644441551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxx\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544362
            },
            {
                "eventId": "34653",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441558605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxx\tDuration: 1.65 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441644362
            }
        ]


        let finalLogDataObject = Object.entries(initialLogDataObject).map(function ([key, item]) {

            let logStreamEventMessage = item.message

            if (logStreamEventMessage.includes("INFO") === true) {

                const formattedLogMessage = (String(logStreamEventMessage)).replace("\n", "")
                const filterByInfoKeyword = formattedLogMessage.split(/[  INFO  ]+/);
                const getInfoLogMessages = filterByInfoKeyword[1];
                const formattedInfoLogMessages = getInfoLogMessages.replace(/\s/g, "");
                const parsedInfoLogMessages = JSON.parse(formattedInfoLogMessages);
                
                console.log('formattedInfoLogMessages: ' + formattedInfoLogMessages)
                return parsedInfoLogMessages

            }
        })
        
        finalLogDataObject = finalLogDataObject.filter(function(x) { return x; })

        console.log(finalLogDataObject)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

handler()
```

Comment: This answer needs to be edited to emphasize in the first paragraph that removing `async` is the preferred solution.  A quick reader of this will assume the point being made is to add `Promise.all()` when that is not the desired solution.

Comment: @jfriend00: Good point, on returning to this it should be more clearly emphasized.  I've made an update to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution here would be to use `reduce` since you're not only filtering, but expecting an array of a different type. The reason why `map` shouldn't be used here is because good coding practice would have the result of `map` being the same size as the array being passed in. (i.e., every item in the array now *maps* onto an new value).

Another point to clarify is that you are referring to, and treating an array as an object. Its not necessary to use the `Object.entries` method, since you're already holding the data as an array.

Keeping in mind the data is held as an array, I'd recommend using the `Array.reduce` method.

```
let finalLogDataObject = initialLogDataObject.reduce(function (running, current) {

            let logStreamEventMessage = current.message

            if (logStreamEventMessage.includes("INFO") === true) {

                const formattedLogMessage = (String(logStreamEventMessage)).replace("\n", "")
                const filterByInfoKeyword = formattedLogMessage.split(/[  INFO  ]+/);
                const getInfoLogMessages = filterByInfoKeyword[1];
                const formattedInfoLogMessages = getInfoLogMessages.replace(/\s/g, "");
                const parsedInfoLogMessages = JSON.parse(formattedInfoLogMessages);

                console.log('formattedInfoLogMessages: ' + formattedInfoLogMessages)
                // formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":3,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
                // formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":2,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
                // formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":1,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
                return [...running, parsedInfoLogMessages]

            }else{
                return running
            }
        }, [])
```

Also you aren't doing any asynchronous operations in your callback, so you don't need to indicate the callback as an `async`. In fact, it simplifies the solution because you won't get a bunch of Promises.

If you plan to implement asynchronous operations in the future, lookup [promise await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)and [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

**Full implementation:**

```js
async function handler() {
    try {
        const initialLogDataObject = [
            {
                "eventId": "12345",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551603,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1685441542538
            },
            {
                "eventId": "12345",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:42.539Z\txxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":3,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1684441542539
            },
            {
                "eventId": "12324",
                "ingestionTime": 1687491551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n",
                "timestamp": 1687941542540
            },
            {
                "eventId": "76543",
                "ingestionTime": 1689441551605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\tDuration: 1.26 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1687491542540
            },
            {
                "eventId": "65754",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441951605,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441593428
            },
            {
                "eventId": "76856",
                "ingestionTime": 1687941551605,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:43.429Z\txxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":2,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441543729
            },
            {
                "eventId": "57645",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxx\n",
                "timestamp": 81687441543430
            },
            {
                "eventId": "567465",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441851605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxx\tDuration: 1.62 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1887441543430
            },
            {
                "eventId": "56476",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551605,
                "message": "START RequestId: xxx Version: $LATEST\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544359
            },
            {
                "eventId": "56885",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441551405,
                "message": "2023-06-22T13:45:44.360Z\txxx\tINFO\t{\"id\":1,\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544360
            },
            {
                "eventId": "45343",
                "ingestionTime": 1644441551605,
                "message": "END RequestId: xxx\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441544362
            },
            {
                "eventId": "34653",
                "ingestionTime": 1687441558605,
                "message": "REPORT RequestId: xxx\tDuration: 1.65 ms\tBilled Duration: 2 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 59 MB\t\n",
                "timestamp": 1687441644362
            }
        ]


        // let finalLogDataObject = Object.entries(initialLogDataObject).map(function ([key, item]) {

        //  let logStreamEventMessage = item.message

        //  if (logStreamEventMessage.includes("INFO") === true) {

        //      const formattedLogMessage = (String(logStreamEventMessage)).replace("\n", "")
        //      const filterByInfoKeyword = formattedLogMessage.split(/[  INFO  ]+/);
        //      const getInfoLogMessages = filterByInfoKeyword[1];
        //      const formattedInfoLogMessages = getInfoLogMessages.replace(/\s/g, "");
        //      const parsedInfoLogMessages = JSON.parse(formattedInfoLogMessages);

        //      console.log('formattedInfoLogMessages: ' + formattedInfoLogMessages)
        //      // formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":3,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
        //      // formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":2,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
        //      // formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":1,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
        //      return parsedInfoLogMessages

        //  }
        // })

        let finalLogDataObject = initialLogDataObject.reduce(function (running, current) {

            let logStreamEventMessage = current.message

            if (logStreamEventMessage.includes("INFO") === true) {

                const formattedLogMessage = (String(logStreamEventMessage)).replace("\n", "")
                const filterByInfoKeyword = formattedLogMessage.split(/[  INFO  ]+/);
                const getInfoLogMessages = filterByInfoKeyword[1];
                const formattedInfoLogMessages = getInfoLogMessages.replace(/\s/g, "");
                const parsedInfoLogMessages = JSON.parse(formattedInfoLogMessages);

                console.log('formattedInfoLogMessages: ' + formattedInfoLogMessages)
                // formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":3,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
                // formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":2,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
                // formattedInfoLogMessages: {"id":1,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
                return [...running, parsedInfoLogMessages]

            }else{
                return running
            }
        }, [])
        
        // here is where I need the object to be [{"id":3,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"id":2,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"id":1,"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]

        console.log(finalLogDataObject)
        // however when i console log i get
        // [
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { { id: 3, key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' } },
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { { id: 2, key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' } },
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { { id: 1, key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' } },
        //     Promise { undefined },
        //     Promise { undefined }
        // ]

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

handler()
```

Comment: Thank you @Eyas Valdez. Your answer was also extremely helpful and much appreciated!